# How to use self-signed certificate to authenticate using Azure Management Library?

Tags: azure, azure-management-api, azure-sdk

Is there a way to use self-signed certificates with [Azure Management Libraries](https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/blob/master/src/OrleansSQLUtils/Storage/RelationalStorage.cs#L267) to log in to Azure?

There doesn't seem to be anything in `SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory` nor does the documentation at [Authenticate with the Azure Management Libraries for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/dotnet-sdk-azure-authenticate?view=azure-dotnet) mention anything besides in GH the [CertificateAuthenticationProvider](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/3f736b5af3851ab99bbaa98483ae537de0d48cfb/src/SdkCommon/ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication/CertificateAuthenticationProvider.cs). This in turn is used by [ApplicationTokenProvider](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/3f736b5af3851ab99bbaa98483ae537de0d48cfb/src/SdkCommon/ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication/ApplicationTokenProvider.cs) that shows up [in a few tests](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ApplicationTokenProvider&type=).

<edit: I found there's an issue for this in GH already at https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/3373. It also outlines a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue about this open in GitHub already and a solution at https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/3373. It looks like sign-in with a certificate will be included in the library in the future.